# How does masking work with int/Integer in java?

Tags: java, byte, javac, unsigned-integer

Since bytes are signed in java, in order to obtain unsigned integer values we mask with 0xFF asper:

```
byte signed  = -1;// -—> 0b11111111
int unsigned = signed & 0xFF;// —-> 0b11111111 & 0b11111111
System.out.println(“unsigned: ”+unsigned);//prints 255 instead of -1 since we masked earlier
```

But when the unsigned `int` is casted to a byte it seems nothing happens to it really i.e.

```
byte resigned = (byte) unsigned;
System.out.println(“resigned: ”+resigned);//same value as earlier signed = -1
```

Taking a closer look at the initial operation

```
int unsigned = signed & 0xFF;// the result of 0b11111111 & 0b11111111 is actually = 0b11111111
```

Even if the value of signed were something else say we had

```
byte  signed  = -44;// -—> 0b11010100
int  unsigned = signed & 0xFF;// the result of 0b11010100 & 0b11111111 is still actually = 0b11010100 
byte resigned = (byte) unsigned;
System.out.println(“resigned: ”+resigned);//same value as signed = -44
```

So it seems nothing really happens to the actual signed value for the unsigned `int` to be possible.

Does masking actually do anything to the (byte) value of an integer or it’s just a way to flag how `javac` should treat the integer?

Comment: Try what happens when you don't do the masking and think about why this happens.

Comment: No, masking does nothing to affect byte values.  It only affects ints.

Comment: @tkausl since you missed the point, have a look at the accepted answer, you may want to think about why this happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> byte signed  = -1;// -—> 0b11111111
> ```

Correct.

> ```
> int unsigned = signed & 0xFF;// —-> 0b11111111 & 0b11111111
> ```

This is not correct.  There are 3 steps.

1. The value of `signed` is converted (sign-extended) to an `int`; i.e. `0b11111111` becomes `0b11111111111111111111111111111111` (= 0xFFFFFFFF)
2. The `0b11111111111111111111111111111111` (= `0xFFFFFFFF`) is ANDed with `0b00000000000000000000000011111111` (= `0x000000FF`) to give `0b00000000000000000000000011111111` (= `0x000000FF`)`
3. `0b00000000000000000000000011111111` (= `0x000000FF`) is assigned to `unsigned`.

(Note: it is important to write this out in full so that you understand what happens.)

> ```
> byte resigned = (byte) unsigned;
> ```

There are two steps here too.

1. The cast `(byte)` converts `0b00000000000000000000000011111111` (= `0x000000FF`)
   to `0b11111111` (= `0xFF`) i.e. it converts the `int` to a `byte`.
2. Then the byte `0b11111111` (= `0xFF`) is assigned to `resigned`.

---

> So it seems nothing really happens to the actual signed value for the unsigned int to be possible.

But something did happen!  The `&` operator started with the sign-extended value `0b11111111111111111111111111111111`  (which represents -1) and converted it to `0b00000000000000000000000011111111` (which represents 255).

And you can *verify* that something happened by running this:

```
  byte signed  = -1; // -—> 0b11111111
  int x = signed;
  System.out.println("x: " + x); // prints -1
```

The fact that you ended up with the same value as you started with doesn't mean that nothing happened.  Something did happen.  You converted the `byte` value `-1` to the `int` value `255`, and then you converted it back to the byte `-1`.

You can also verify this by reading the relevant sections of the Java Language Specification.   (Let me know if you need the references.)

---

> Does masking actually do anything to the (byte) value of an integer or it’s just a way to flag how javac should treat the integer?

Masking really did something.

---

If you were to look at the bytecodes produced by the `javac` compiler you would see codes to do the `byte` to `int` conversion, the masking and the assignment.  Then in the other direction, you would see a bytecode to do an `int` to `byte` conversion.

However, that is an implementation detail.

Comment: firstly, thank you for simply understanding the problem. secondly thanks for taking your time to explain